# Case Like doesn't work in VBA

Tags: vba

I have the following code in VBA, However, although I have the value in my cell which is "PAR-DDD-CHEAP", The case like doesn't work and the code would jump straight to end select.

can someone shed some light on this?

```
                Select Case CStr(nRg.Value)
                  Case CStr(nRg.Value) Like "PAR-DDD*", "PAR-BBB*", "PAR-GGG*"

                    If nRg.Offset(0, 6).Value = "NEW" Then
                    nRg.Offset(0, 8).Value = sResult.Offset(-18, 0)
                    ElseIf nRg.Offset(0, 6).Value <> "NEW" Then
                    nRg.Offset(0, 8).Value = sResult.Offset(-9, 0)
                    End If
                  End Select
```

I have even tested the statement of  `Case CStr(nRg.Value) = "PAR-DDD-CHEAP"`, the VBA still jump straight to the end select.

Comment: http://ccm.net/faq/36211-vba-using-the-like-operator-with-select-case

Answer (score 0):

LIKE comparison returns True or False so SELECT CASE must test for True. Have to repeat comparison for each value using OR operator.

```
Select Case True
    Case nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-DDD*" OR nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-BBB*" OR nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-GGG*"
```

Could just use `If nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-DDD*" OR nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-BBB*" OR nRg.Value LIKE "PAR-GGG*" Then`.