# Excel VBA Case Statement with Like conditions not working as excpected

Tags: excel, sql-like, case-statement, vba

Good morning,

I'm having a similar issue to: [Case Like doesn't work in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887517/case-like-doesnt-work-in-vba)

Basically, when we are using the LIKE operator we're getting different results that we believe we should. Hers seems to just jump to the end with no results, but mine uses the first Case, and only the first case while ignoring the rest even if they don't match.

My desired effect is I would like to select a range of cells and for each cell in the range, loop an export the value to a text file with a different prefix depending on the cell column:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim r As Excel.Range, cell As Excel.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Select Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Open "C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\Macro Results\text.txt" For Output As #1
    For Each cell In r
        Select Case CellVal
            Case cell.Address Like "$A$#"
                Print #1, "Last Name: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case cell.Address Like "$B$#"
                Print #1, "First Name: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
    Case cell.Address Like "$C$#"
                'Do Nothing Print #1, "First Name: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
    Case cell.Address Like "$F$#"
                Print #1, "Email: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
    Case cell.Address Like "$G$#"
                Print #1, "Phone#: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
    Case cell.Address Like "$H$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$I$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$J$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$K$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$L$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$M$#"
                'Do Nothing 
    Case cell.Address Like "$N$#"
                Print #1, "Token Type: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
    Case cell.Address Like "$O$#"
                Print #1, "Token#:" + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next
    Close
End Sub
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
Last Name: 
First Name: 
Email: 
Phone#: 
Token Type: 
Token#:
```

I didn't want to add each individual cell column for the like statements, but in a test macro, I was able to successfully differentiate between the A and B column with this technique. It does not work in the final spreadsheet.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to variable `CellVal` so right off the bat you have a logical cerror: `CellVal` will always be empty/nullstring unless you assign to it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the error, which may mean that it auto defines it, but I've since done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply base your `Case` off of the cell's `.Column`?  No need to use fuzzy Like operators/etc.

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Excel.Range, cell As Excel.Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Select Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Open "C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\Macro Results\text.txt" For Output As #1
    For Each cell In r
        Select Case cell.Column
            Case 1
                Print #1, "Last Name: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case 2
                Print #1, "First Name: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case 6
                Print #1, "Email: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case 7
                Print #1, "Phone#: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case 14
                Print #1, "Token Type: " + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case 15
                Print #1, "Token#:" + cell.Value + " " + cell.Address
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next
    Close
End Sub
```

**Update from comments re: Type Mismatch**

The Type Mismatch arises from your use of `+` as a string concatentor. In VBA, you can use either `+` or `&`.  The quirk is that if you attempt to use `+` when dealing with mixed data types (integer/long, string, etc.) then it may attempt to use it as a mathematical operator (addition sign).  Avoid this in sevaral different ways:

**My preference** is to always use the `&` as a string concatenator:

```
 Print #1, "Token#:" & cell.Value & " " + cell.Address
```

**Alternatively** cast the value to a string variable (which you have figured out).

```
 Dim v as String
 v = cell.value
 Print #1, "Token#:" + v + " " + cell.Address
```

**Another alternative** cast to string directly:

```
 Print #1, "Token#:" + CStr(cell.Value) + " " + cell.Address
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "Type Mismatch" error for column 15, but it works on all the others. The 'O' column is usually a 9 digit integer, any reason why it would be throwing this error? Update: NM, I just put a string and set it to the cell value: Dim v As String
                v = cell.Value
                Print #1, "Token#:" + v + " " + cell.Address

Comment: Cheers. I've made an update to explain why you got that error. You found one way to resolve it, but I show you two other methods to fix it :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that '&' was a string concatenator. I think I'd go with that way as well. This is all working very nicely now and really saving us time. Thanks again for your help!